# How to login to internet using web based login while installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates, internet

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop. But I have an internet connection that requires web based login, where an ISP page in internet browser opens and I have to login to internet using the username and password to start browsing the web.
While installing ubuntu, it tries to download some updates via internet. I am stuck here as I cannot download updates before having to login to internet. Is there any method to login or bypass this situation??

Comment: Why not open Firefox and login before clicking the Install button?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

1. Boot into the live cd and setup the wireless then start the install by clicking the icon on the desktop.
2. While installing Ubuntu uncheck ‘Download updates while installing’.

Comment: 1)I unchecked Download Updates while installing, but it still tries to retrieve updates from internet. 2) I have wired internet and not wireless

Comment: Can you get the network to work on the live cd?